# Предпочтения в sql запросе

Tags: sql

Есть запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE accepted = true or id = 1
```

Как написать такой запрос что бы сначала искал по accepted, если не нашел accepted = true, то искал по id?

Comment: SQL - декларативный язык. Вы пишете, что хотите получить, а сервер делает это наилучшим образом, выбирая план, который для данных, которые хранятся в БД, для ресурсов доступных БД и заданой конфигурации БД будет оптимальным. Иногда можно заставить БД делать запрос именно в определенном порядке. Для этого нужно знать какая СУБД используется (включая версию). И понимать, что в большинстве случаев СУБД лучше оптимизирует этот запрос чем вы.

Comment: если вам сильно хочется, чтобы поиск делался именно в таком порядке, тогда сделайте два отдельных запроса, где в первом будет `where accepted = true`, а во втором `where id = 1`

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук а как их в sql-то запрос вставить что бы приоритет первому отдавался?

Comment: @ks_on_v Не знаю. Не уверен, что это возможно. От перестановки этих условий результат выборки не меняется. По этому sql-сервер может делать поиск по своему усмотрению. Хотя можно сделать дополнительные индекс на колонку `accepted`, тогда с большим шансом sql-сервер сначала проверит колонку с индексом, а потом уже остальные колонки, т.е. `id`

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук с чего вы взяли, что автору нужен порядок поиска? Ему результат нужен. Если есть с accepted= 1, то только их показать. Если они отсутствуют, то найти по id=1. Никто тут не говорил про указания серверу что искать в каком порядке.

Comment: @teran ок, если так.

Answer (score 1):

такую логику можно выстроить примерно так.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE accepted = 1

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE id = 1 
     AND 0 = ( select count(*) from t where accepted = 1)
```

но проще, навреное обойтись выборкой данных по обоим условиям и сортировкой по обоим полям. Или вообще выполнять два запроса в клиенте.